# Lua - get table hex identifier

Tags: lua, lua-table

I want to know how to get the table hex id. I know that doing:

```
local some_var = {}
print (some_var)
```

the result is (for instance):

```
table: 0x21581c0
```

I want the hex without the `table:` string. I know that maybe some of you suggest me to make a regular expression (or something similar) to remove those chars, but I want to avoid that, and just get the `0x21581c0`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard implementation, there is the global 'print' variable that refers to a standard function that calls, through the global variable 'tostring', a standard function described [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-tostring). The stanard 'tostring' function is the only way to retrieve the hexadecimal number it shows for a table.

Unfortunately, there is no configuration for either of the functions to do anything differently for all tables.

Nonetheless, there are several points for modification. You can create you own function and call that every time instead, or point either of the the global variables `print` or `tostring` to you own functions. Or, set a `__tostring` metamethod on each table you need `tostring` to return a different answer for. The advantage to this is it gets you the format you want with only one setup step. The disadvantage is that you have to set up each table.

```
local function simplifyTableToString(t)
   local answer = tostring(t):gsub("table: ", "", 1)
   local mt = getmetatable(t) 
   if not mt then
      mt = {}
      setmetatable(t, mt)
   end
   mt.__tostring = function() return answer end
end

local a = {}
local b = {}    
print(a, b)
simplifyTableToString(a)
print(a, b)
```

Comment: Yep, I wanted to avoid the regular expression stuff, but it seems that there isn't another way. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is simpler and works for all types that are associated with pointers:

```lua
local function getId(t)
  return string.format("%p", t)
end

print("string:", getId("hi"))
print("table:", getId({}))
print("userdata:", getId(io.stdin))
print("function:", getId(print))
print("number:", getId(1))
print("boolean:", getId(false))
print("nil:", getId(nil))
```

Result:

```
string: 0x0109f04638
table: 0x0109f0a270
userdata: 0x01098076c8
function: 0x0109806018
number: NULL
boolean: NULL
nil: NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

Without complex patterns, you can just search for the first space, and grab the substring of what follows.

```
function get_mem_addr (object)
    local str = tostring(object)    
    return str:sub(str:find(' ') + 1)
end

print(get_mem_addr({})) -- 0x109638
print(get_mem_addr(function () end)) -- 0x108cf8
```

This function will work with tables and functions, but expect errors if you pass it anything else.

Or you can use a little type checking:

```
function get_mem_addr (o)
    return tostring(o):sub(type(o):len() + 3)
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does nor work with tables with __tostring metatable. I do not know solution for this without C code.

Answer (score 0):

The table id stated by the OP is invalid in the version of Lua I am using (5.1 in Roblox). A valid ID is length 8, not 9 as in your example. Either way, just use string.sub to get the sub-string you are after.

```
string.sub(tostring({}), 8)
```

The reason is, 'table: ' is 7 characters long, so we take from index 8 through the end of the string which returns the hex value.